# Perl - combine two split commands into one

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that I was cleaning up, it works very well, but I was wondering if anyone knows of a good way to combine 2 splits into one command.

I have a .csv file, like this small example:

```
Move_VALIDATE,020212191ABC01,SNSNT---01CAB101A-1-1-4-20,circuit 402339-1,interface 1/1/0
Move_VALIDATE,030323202ABC01,SNSNT01CAB101A-1-1-4-20,circuit 303559-1,interface 2/2/0
```

Section in script with the two splits:

```
foreach my $line (@file_array){
my $CHECK_ID = (split /,/, $line) [2];
my @SPLIT_ID = (split /-/, $CHECK_ID);
my $FINAL_ID = ($CHECK_ID =~ /---/) ? "$SPLIT_ID[0]---$SPLIT_ID[3]" : "$SPLIT_ID[0]";
print "$FINAL_ID\n";
}
```

Output:

```
SNSNT---01CAB101A
SNSNT01CAB101A
```

Comment: Thanks DavidO for the edit update. First post for me and the back ticks threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have long lines with many fields, it pays to limit how many fields you are asking `split` to return. In this case, you need the third field, so you want to limit split to four fields.

Second, it is easier to remove the part you don't need at the end of the field.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    (my $id = (split /,/, $line, 4)[2]) =~ s/(?:-[0-9]{1,2})+\z//;
    print "$id\n";
}

__DATA__
Move_VALIDATE,020212191ABC01,SNSNT---01CAB101A-1-1-4-20,circuit 402339-1,interface 1/1/0
Move_VALIDATE,030323202ABC01,SNSNT01CAB101A-1-1-4-20,circuit 303559-1,interface 2/2/0
```

```
$ ./klklj.pl
SNSNT---01CAB101A
SNSNT01CAB101A
```

Comment: This solution works well for me. I can understand all but the {1,2} in:(my $id = (split /,/, $line, 4)[2]) =~ s/(?:-[0-9]{1,2})+\z//; Does it mean match at least once max of twice?

Comment: @user3577012: `[0-9]{1,2}` matches one or two digits, so the sequence `(?:-[0-9]{1,2})` matches a hyphen `-` followed by one or two digits. The substitution removes as many of these as possible up to the end of the id, so `-1-1-4-20` from the first and `-1-1-4-20` from the second. This is a different algorithm from the one your code uses that just happens to produce the same result with the two records you show so you should be careful with it.

Comment: @user3577012: I think I would prefer `my ($id) = (split /,/, $line, 4)[2] =~ /([^-]+(?:---[^-]+)?)/`, which produces a result much closer to your own code. It looks for a sequence of non-hyphen characters, followed optionally by three hyphens and another sequence of non-hyphens

Answer (score 0):

You can use one split for commas as you have it and use word-boundary assertion for the second one, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    printf qq|%s\n|, (split /\b-\b/, (split /,/, $_)[2])[0];
}


__DATA__
Move_VALIDATE,020212191ABC01,SNSNT---01CAB101A-1-1-4-20,circuit 402339-1,interface 1/1/0
Move_VALIDATE,030323202ABC01,SNSNT01CAB101A-1-1-4-20,circuit 303559-1,interface 2/2/0
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

That yields:

```
SNSNT---01CAB101A
SNSNT01CAB101A
```